# Math in $[ ] expansions not honored across all shells

Tags: shell

I use Debian.
The problem is that when i type `echo $[1+2]` in the terminal,the result is `3`.
However when I write `echo $[1+2]` in the a shell file, the result is `$[1+2]`.

Comment: your terminal shell is probably `bash` or `zsh` as a consequence of which `$[1+2]` is treated as an arithmetic expansion. Your shell script might be executing under `sh`, try `bash shell_script_file` instead?

Comment: You are executing the script using `sh`.

Comment: The POSIX sh syntax for arithmetic, supported by Debian's ash and dash as well as modern shells, is `$(( 1 + 2 ))`. What you're using is ancient Bourne. Don't do that.

Comment: (Historical note: Despite its name, bash is actually more closely related to ksh than to original Bourne; the POSIX sh specification, similarly, was built with reference to an old version of the Korn shell. Consequently, trying to be compatible with Bourne is only very rarely worthwhile).

Comment: By the way, it's not `echo` doing the expansion in **any** shell; in all situations, the expansion is done before the command (in this case echo) is started, and without specific reference to what that command is.

Comment: @devnull, why did you delete your answer here? Looks applicable and useful.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, how about following your own advice and putting all those comments into an answer ;-)

Comment: Heh. If the history is important, fair 'nuff; I'll build an appropriate answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The POSIX sh syntax for arithmetic, supported by Debian's ash and dash as well as modern shells, is `$(( 1 + 2 ))`. The `$[ 1 + 2 ]` syntax is ancient Bourne, and not part of POSIX sh.

Despite its name, bash is actually more closely related to ksh than to original Bourne; the POSIX sh specification, similarly, was built with reference to an old version of the Korn shell. Consequently, trying to be compatible with Bourne is only very rarely worthwhile.